# No http referer set when non logged in user comes from inner pages to home page

Tags: wordpress

I am  trying to load a preloader gif when user comes to the website for first time

I am using this code :

```
<?php 
$find = 'example.com';
echo $referer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; 
echo $pos = strpos($referer, $find);
if(!$pos):?>
<div id="site-preloader">
    <img src="http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/loader.gif" class="preload-img">
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {  
  jQuery(window).load(function(){
    jQuery('#site-preloader').delay(350).fadeOut('slow',function(){jQuery(this).remove();});
  });
});
</script>
```

This code works absolutely fine when user is logged in .

But when user is not logged in and if user navigates to home page from some inner page or post then the code doesn't work because http_referer is not set

What can be wrong ..

Please help